# Can Pandas merge data conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, merge, conditional-statements, match

In Python's Pandas library, I would like to merge 2 tables but have the columns they merge left and right on, change based on a condition per row. For example, I have table called dfpivot that has columns ['WD.Fund_Worktag', 'WD.CC_Worktag', 'WD.PG_Worktag', 'WD.SC_Worktag'] and second table named df1pivot with columns ['Fund', 'Cost Center', 'Program', 'Spend Category as Worktag'], each column matching respectively. In the instance when 'WD.CC_Worktag', 'WD.PG_Worktag' in dfpivot are equal to "N/A" for a given row I would like the left on and right on to change to ['WD.Fund_Worktag', 'WD.SC_Worktag'] and ['Fund', 'Spend Category as Worktag'], respectively. The below codes is what I attempted but is unsucessful. Any help is appreciated!

```
# Initialize empty lists for left_on and right_on
left_on_list = []
right_on_list = []

# Iterate over rows of dfpivot
for index, row in dfpivot.iterrows():
    if row['WD.CC_Worktag'] == 'N/A' and row['WD.PG_Worktag'] == 'N/A':
        left_on_list.append(['WD.Fund_Worktag', 'WD.SC_Worktag'])
        right_on_list.append(['Fund', 'Spend Category as Worktag'])
    else:
        left_on_list.append(['WD.Fund_Worktag', 'WD.CC_Worktag', 'WD.PG_Worktag', 'WD.SC_Worktag'])
        right_on_list.append(['Fund', 'Cost Center', 'Program', 'Spend Category as Worktag'])

# Merge based on the dynamically created left_on and right_on lists
merged_pivot = pd.merge(dfpivot, df1pivot, left_on=left_on_list, right_on=right_on_list, how='left')
```

Comment: you may have to join every row separately.

Comment: please try to reproduce the two datasets with a few rows that cover the examples you would like us to factor in. Also, reproduce the output dataframe with those many rows